How to obfuscate request to WCF webHttpBinding?
I have a WCF service using webHttpBinding (post method).
I want to obfuscate the request (post json data) using XOR or base64... and deobfucate the request on the server.
I wonder how to implement an IHttpModule or IHttpHandler to do it on the server side!
I am using C#, .NET, VS2019.
